# Using numeric ranges in a case statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm facing trouble in getting the cases executed. Every time, it goes to the last case i.e. * characters.

Here's what I'm using:

```
case $used_space in
    [1-84])
        echo "OK - $used_space% of disk space used."
        exit 0
        ;;
    [85])
        echo "WARNING - $used_space% of disk space used."
        exit 1
        ;;
    [86-100]*)
        echo "CRITICAL - $used_space% of disk space used."
        exit 2
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$used_space% of disk space used."
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

How can I change my case statement to work with numeric ranges?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Hi Cyrus, this dump is from that website only.
I dont know what Ranges can only match single chars (mentioned due to duplicates). means in this case.

Comment: If i do it like this:  if (( $used_space => 1 && used_space <= 84 ))
as the link states, i am thrown : Couldn't parse this ((..)) command.

Comment: @RainaM: There is no `=>`. Generally you should be more careful with your syntax. Every character matters. For example, you write `$used_space` in the first expression and `used_space` in the second. Which works, but only inside an arithmetic evaluation (`(( ))`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With bash and case:

```
case $used_space in
  [1-9]|[1-7][0-9]|8[0-4]) # range 1-84
    echo "OK - $used_space% of disk space used."
    exit 0
    ;;
  85)
    echo "WARNING - $used_space% of disk space used."
    exit 1
    ;;
  8[6-9]|9[0-9]|100)        # range 86-100
    echo "CRITICAL - $used_space% of disk space used."
    exit 2
    ;;
  *)
    echo "$used_space% of disk space used."
    exit 3
     ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrus.
This Reg-ex like syntax was what i was looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Just use series of if-s, like this:

```
if [[ "$used_space" -le 84 && "$used_space" -ge 1 ]]
then
    echo "OK - $used_space% of disk space used."
    exit 0
elif [[ "$used_space" -eq 85 ]]
then
    echo "WARNING - $used_space% of disk space used."
    exit 1
elif [[ "$used_space" -gt 85 && "$used_space" -le 100 ]]
then
    echo "CRITICAL - $used_space% of disk space used."
    exit 2
else
    echo "$used_space% of disk space used."
    exit 3
fi
```

Comment: There are numerous way to do this, including `[[`, `[` and `((`. The link posted in comments recommends `((`. Maybe a little note on the difference between those three could be useful too.

Comment: There is a nice article about test constructs in bash http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/

Comment: `((` can be used for arithmetic expressions. `[[` is useful for string tests, but it does its job in the example above, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the alternative Jakub!